# Goggle chromecast cast autoplay is not working when the device is locked / idle

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I am working on autoplay with Google Chrome Cast, When the app in background state or device is locked / idle, the app playing one video next video is not playing, how to enable autoplay when the app in background mode or device locked.

When the device is locked GCKSession going into suspended state. How to overcome the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly you have to check all the basic functionality of chromcast, why [chromecast stopped working](https://www.geekyarea.com/how-to-fix-chromecast-not-working-issue/).

1.WiFi Network

2.WiFi Connectivity

3.WiFi Frequency

4.Factory Reset

5.Reset your Router

6.Update Router’s Firmware

You can check all the checklist which are mention above.

Thank you.